How can I reset the admin password for OpenLDAP on Fedora?
I am on Fedora and set up an OpenLDAP server. I don't remember ever setting an admin password to begin with, but I am having to perform operations where the admin password is prompted. Entering nothing doesn't work. I have done extensive searching about the issue, and have tried the following:
$ ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}wDiv2teFapZFmOwSz04/2CMaYvpqfLvi
E0F
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for User: 
[root@localhost ~]# ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}wDiv2teFapZFmOwSz04/2CMaYvpqfLvi
E0F
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

$ ldapsearch -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b  cn=config olcRootDN=cn=admin,dc=com,dc=example  dn olcRootDN olcRootPW
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=1000+uidNumber=1000,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
No such object (32)

$ sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b 'cn=config'
[sudo] password for User: 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=config
> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1

$ sudo ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}wDiv2teFapZFmOwSz04/2CMaYvpqfLvi
E0F
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

I also put the above into a file and tried this:
$ vim pw_reset.ldif
$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -D 'cn=config' -H ldapi:/// -f ./pw_reset.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

So, the obvious problem here is that no matter what, I don't seem to have "sufficient access," which is the problem here. I need the admin password to set the admin password. What is the proper way to do this?

There likely was no admin password; instead your system probably had database ACLs (the olcAccess attribute) set up so that they grant all privileges to UID 0 "peercred" connections – before that broke, anyway. (That's how distros install Postgres and MariaDB as well.)
Shut down the service, then use slapadd -n 0 / slapmodify -n 0 to directly apply changes to the backend database, then start the service again. (Make sure to sudo it to the correct user account, 'slapd' or 'ldap' or similar, to avoid accidentally creating root-owned files that the service won't be able to read.)
The cn=config suffix always uses a text-file database, so in a pinch you could even edit the slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase=*.ldif using any text editor.
Remember that the rootDN (as well as olcAccess) is separate for each suffix (database instance) so you will need to change it also for olcDatabase={0}config, not just for olcDatabase{1}mdb (and it's the former that actually lets you perform config changes – the latter is merely for managing data).

Right on - the other issue in this case was that there was absolutely nothing in /etc/openldap/slapd.d even though "dynamic config" was being used. So therefore, none of this stuff really existed. I have a feeling it got accidentally deleted after install somehow. I kept getting object not found errors in addition to those permission ones. So I used -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d as arguments to the service which essentially re-spawned my default dynamic config and populated the slapd.d directory (see man slapd), allowing me to follow the rest of these steps.

In that case, you could have simplified the steps by editing slapd.conf directly to set the rootdn/rootpw and then converting it to LDIF format.
